# Is there any way that we can get location or locale of Facebook Page from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have trying to get location or locale of facebook page using graph API.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{page-id}/locations
```

I have tried with above get request, but its is not giving any results.

So, my doubt is does facebook gives us the location information of the page, if yes then how would be request will look like.

Comment: That edge is for _“the location Pages that are children of this Page”_ (quote docs) – is that really what you are after, does the page in question _have_ child pages for different locations? I think you might rather want the value of the `location` _field_ of the page.

Comment: @CBroe yeah you are right I want the location of the page only.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example with a page id an arbitrary page id (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/1234/locations) and got this JSON response:

```
{ 
  "error": { 
    "message": "(#12) user locations API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 12 
  } 
}
```

So this API seems to be deprecated since version 2.0. In an earlier version it seems to work (https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/1234/locations).

Comment: _“I've tried your example with a page id an arbitrary page id”_ – and that’s where you went wrong already, because `1234` is not a page id, but a user id.

Comment: @thomas_b: API is in v2.2, is is not deprecated,

Comment: @CBroe: did u get any results with your test? I haven't got any JSON response with valid page-id.